# I would like to log in different file for each type, and in different directory for each thread

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using Log4j (from spring-boot-starter-log4j2 
In my application, each Datafilter class handles different type of data.
Datafilter is a runnable class and we create multiple instance of it.

Requirement is such that, I want to log each type of data in each file, inside a directory for each thread.

***Example : If DataFilter handles T1, T2, T3 type of data, and If I spawn 3 instance of DataFilter, Log4j2 must create 3 directories (1,2,3) , and each directory must contain log files for type of data (ex in directory "1" : 1-T1.log 1-T2.log 1-T3.log)***

---

This is my log4j2 configuration :

```
<Appenders>
    <!-- File Appender -->
    <File name="FILE" fileName="${basePath}/logfile.log"
        append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${logFileMsgPattern}" />
    </File>

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </Console>

    <Routing name="Routing">
        <Routes pattern="${ctx:type}">
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="RollingFile-${ctx:type}"
                    fileName="${basePath}/${ctx:threadId}/${ctx:threadId}-${ctx:type}.log"
                    filePattern="/${basePath}/${ctx:threadId}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/archived_%d{HH-mm}-${ctx:type}.log">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="${logMetricMsgPattern}" />
                    <Policies>
                        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                    </Policies>
                     <Filters>
                        <!-- First deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
                        <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>

                        <!-- Then accept info, warn, error, fatal and deny debug/trace -->
                        <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
                    </Filters>
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>           
    </Routing>
</Appenders>
```

---

Every thread I create I propagate the ThreadContext.
I printed the value of it, the ThreadContext values are proper.

If I modify `<Routes pattern="${ctx:type}">` to `<Routes pattern="${ctx:threadId}">` , I dont see the log directories for different thread. Looks like something has to be done with the Pattern.

Any solutions and resources regarding what pattern will be greatly appreciated.